# How to send props to state other components in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to send props to other components state and it's not working... Why ?

```
    const Footer = (props) => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);


    return (
        <>
            <Test {...props} />
        </>
    );
}

const Test = (props) => {

    const [testState, setTestState] = useState(props);

    console.log(testState);

    return (
        <>
        </>
    );
}
export default Test;
```

I get undefined value

Comment: Avoid assigning the props of one component to state of other component(s) as when the props will change the state will not be updated and thus the changes will not be reflected

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
```

Add these two lines top of the code

And Call the Footer Component like that
`<Footer name={"Hello"} />`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Footer = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <Test {...props} />
        </>
    );
};

const Test = (props) => {
    const [testState, setTestState] = useState(props);

    console.log(testState);

    return <></>;
};
export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Footer = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <Test {...props} open={open} />
        </>
    );
}
```

1, you should check the props from Footer component

2, maybe you should send Footer state to Test component like this?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling Footer component? If you are not passing any props to

```
 <Footer />
```

do it like

```
<Footer propname="somevalue" />
```

And then it will log the props to console.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are sending props from Footer component to Test component and then used same in state of Test component. This makes Footer as parent component and Test as child component. But final export statement is not considering parent component (Footer).
I assume you are using Footer component in your page
like

```
<Footer notes="Sample Notes"/>
```

If not then props is undefined . Try to send some properties and see .

Also, try changing the last line to

```
export default Footer
```